# ¿Cómo validar una fecha en PHP?

Tags: php

Estoy intentando comprobar, más bien validar, que la **fecha de nacimiento** que el usuario me proporciona es menor que la fecha actual del sistema.

¿Alguien me podría ayudar? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Deberías poner el código que has intentado y sobre este sería mas fácil ayudarte con tu problema

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de la función `PHP` llamada `strtotime`

> Aquí el link de la documentación > [Strtotime](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php)

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de ese método en ejecución...

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");
    $end = '2017-12-29';
    $fecha_actual = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
    $fecha_nacimiento = strtotime($end);

        if($fecha_actual > $fecha_nacimiento){
            echo "fecha correcta";
        }else{
            echo "fecha incorrecta";
        }                   
?>
```

Con `date_default_timezone_set` establecemos la zona horaria (lo pongo ya que varias veces `PHP` me regresa horas incorrectas aunque mi `php.ini` tenga establecido correctamente la zona)

En la variable `$end` establecemos la fecha de nacimiento, que bien, puede ser recibida de un formulario con `$end = $_POST['idElementoDondeSeIngresaLaFechaDeNacimiento'];`

En la variable `$fecha_actual` recogemos la fecha con formato año-mes(numero)-dia(numero) hora(con formato de 24 horas)-minutos-segundos

Y el `if` simplemente compara ambas variables, espero que te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Muy bueno tu código, sin embargo la función `strtotime()` no es necesaria cuando utilizas la función `date()`

Answer (score 1):

Viendo todas las respuestas me parece importante puntualizar que se pueden comparar strings en el formato `YYYY-MM-DD` y funciona perfectamente porque la comparación de strings falla en cuanto alguno de los elementos caracteres es menor o mayor al elemento comparado.

Encima la solución termina siendo más sencilla:

```
echo '2017-12-29' >= date("Y-m-d") ? 'Fecha inválida' : 'Fecha válida';
```

Solo debes recordar como indica @antonio291093 que es necesario fijar `date_default_timezone_set()` si no has configurado correctamente tu timezone en `php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

Si eres mas especifico de como lo recibes la fecha, podría ser mas explicito pero te dejo esto:

```
$fecha_recibida = $_POST['fecha']; //Tiene que estar en el formato 2017-11-29
$fecha_enviada = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',$fecha_recibida));
$fecha_actual = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));

if ($fecha_actual > $fecha_enviada) {
    # code
}
```